# Deleting background apps

Tags: keyboard, finder

You know when you're on the mac and you tap f4 and all these apps and games you already deleted is still there. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question isn't clear enough for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. Can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to clarify _how_ you are deleting your Apps? Also, can you confirm that by tapping the F4 key you mean that it launches the Launchpad? For many users the F4 key will launch the Dashboard, and of course people can customise what it does, so we can't assume we know what it's doing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apps can exist anywhere on macOS. Use spotlight to search for the apps you want to delete and see if you have multiple copies.

When that's done, you need to rebuild your spotlight index. That feeds both spotlight search and the launchpad icon list.